# Randomize the decimal in integer numbers to avoid overlapping data points in chart

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm creating a chart and because my data has integers without decimal (e.g. 5 or -4) I'm getting too many overlapping points.

Is there a way to transform those integers and randomize the decimal? So I would have X-Y coordinates like 5.05 X -4.15 Y.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`RAND`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rand-function-4cbfa695-8869-4788-8d90-021ea9f5be73?NS=EXCEL&Version=90&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZXL900&HelpId=xlmain11.chm60111&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) function to create a random number between 0 and 1. So if you want to add a random fraction to an integer, just add `RAND()` to the integer:

```
=A2+RAND()
```

You can use a couple of helper columns to create the new coordinates like this:

[image]

Note that the numbers returned by `RAND` will change every time the sheet is recalculated. If you don't want this to happen, you can copy the randomised numbers from the "X-Rand" and "Y-Rand" columns and paste using `Paste Special | Values` either to a third set of columns or on top of the "X" and "Y" columns.

As JvdV points out in a comment, instead of adding just any random decimal to the integers, you may want the decimal to be quite small so that the result is not very different from the original integer. In that case, you can divide the random number by some arbitrary value. For example, dividing the random number by 10 will ensure that the decimal is never more than 0.1.

```
=A2+RAND()/10
```

Comment: Randbetween would be better in this case since OP is using integers, RAND might end up putting decimals close to the next integer, making it hard to distinguish between a point that actually belongs to the higher integer and one lower.

Comment: @JvdV That's true, although if the goal is simply to keep the results close to the original integer, it might be simpler to just use something like `RAND()/10`. I'll add that as an option.

Answer (score 1):

With vales in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=A1
```

in **B2** enter:

```
=A2+0.00001*(COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)-1)
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: This is a nice answer because it avoids the volatility of the “RAND” function.    Note that if 0.00001 isn’t working for your graphing, you could use 0.001 or 0.05 or something that works with your graph’s scale.